# Inverse oval in CSS

Tags: css, inverse, oval

How i can make inverse oval in css as on image (layer)?

I want footer on webpage. Starting position on: bottom: 0px; right: 0px;

[image]

This is my test but is bad.

```css
.inverseoval{
background-color: #ff3300;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 20px;
     height:30px;
     width:400px;
     border: 3px solid #000000;
     border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
     border-radius: 50% / 100%;
     border-top-left-radius: 0;
     border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="inverseoval"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something with pseudo-elements like `:before` . Other solution would be with SVG but i made an answer just with a `:before` element.

Add it to the `inverseoval` div and shape it and position it how you want.

Be careful to give it the same `background-color` as for the `content`.

```css
.content {
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.inverseoval {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inverseoval:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

</div>
<div class="inverseoval"></div>
```